# What CAD software is depicted in this screenshot?

Tags: macos, applications, software, drawing

This screenshot (source [here](https://butterflyfish.de/ein-hochbett-selber-bauen/)) apparently depicts a CAD software (German version) for macOS:

[image: Screenshot of CAD software, with menu and status-bar text in German.]

What software is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The software is called SketchUp. I believe this may be the pro version.

Answer (score 3):

This is [SketchUP](https://www.sketchup.com). SketchUp was developed by startup company @Last Software, released in August 2000. It stayed under Google from March 14, 2006 to  June 1, 2012 when Trimble Navigation (now Trimble Inc.) acquired it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SketchUp#@Last_Software

[image]